# Convertendo InputStream em Imagem

Tags: android, imagem

Preciso realizar download de uma imagem e grava-la no aparelho.
Faço o download dela e gravo em um `InputSstream`

```
InputStream imagem = comunicacao.getWSStream(servico, nome);
```

Mas na hora de converte-la, o decodebyteArray acaba gerando um null.

```
 private void gravaImagem(InputStream imagem, String nome){
    try {
        FileOutputStream escrita = new FileOutputStream(new File(SivaPlusConfig.DIRETORIO_SDIMG + nome));
        byte[] bytes = readBytes(imagem);
        Bitmap imagem2 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length); // gera null
        if (imagem2 == null) {
            return;
        }
        imagem2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, escrita);
        escrita.flush();
        escrita.close();
        imagem.close();
    } catch (Exception e){
        LogUtil.writeFile((Activity) mContext, "Erro ao gravar imagem: " + nome);
    }
}

 private byte[] readBytes(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            bos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
        return bytes;
    } finally {
        bos.close();
    }
}
```

Desculpe pela formatação do texto. Ainda estou me adaptando e aprendendo sobre a comunidade.

Comment: Você poderia simplesmente utilizar as bibliotecas do Glide ou Picasso que já fazem quase isso tudo com poucas linhas de código.

Comment: @MárcioOliveira obrigado pela resposta mas pretendo não utilizar biblioteca de terceiros.

Comment: Bom, que tal umas validações de segurança primeiro para analizar o problema. No método gravaImagem, antes de utilizar a variável bytes, convém controlar que não se encontra a null e que bytes.length >0.

Só com o código apresentado, o problema pode originar de várias instrucções, até em permissões de acesso ao cartão SD e/ou validar que o mesmo existe. 
Sugeria que adicione as sugestões que forneci para mais precisamente localizar o problema.

Comment: @Gabriel, ok, só sugeri porque são bibliotecas clássicas e muito utilizadas (inclusive em alguns apps da própria Google) que fazem um excelente trabalho.

Comment: @MárcioOliveira claro, entendo. Mas é que é um pouco mais complicado conseguir usar essas bibliotecas onde trabalho.

Comment: @PedroFerreira entendo mas o estranho é que eu recebo todos os dados. Tanto o InputStream como o bytes estão populados mas na hora de utilizar o decodeByteArray o método gera null para imagem2

Comment: Null no decodeByte ou no compress? O que estás a tentar fazer no compress não é possível sem fazeres uma cópia do bitmap para ser mutable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalizado. Era problema no webservice, "Content-Type" estava diferente do esperado. Obrigado pela ajuda.